# How do I combine the upper.tri of one matrix with the lower.tri of another in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have two symmetrical matrices of the same lengths (one contains correlation coefficients and the other contains p-values).

I'm trying to make a matrix such that the upper.tri contains correlation coefficients and the lower.tri contains the relevant p-values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your matrices are `correl` and `pval`

```
# create a new matrix that is the pvalues
new <- pval
# not sure what you want the diagonal to be, lets make it NA
diag(new) <- NA
# replace the upper triangle of this new matrix with the 
# upper triangle of the correlation matrix
new[upper.tri(new)] <- correl[upper.tri(correl)]
```

Comment: do you mean correl[upper.tri(correl)]?

Comment: @Atticus29 If they are the same size, it shouldn't matter. `upper.tri` just returns a bunch of logical TRUE/FALSEes with the trues in the upper triangle. Try `upper.tri(matrix(1:9,ncol=3))`

Comment: @thelatemail I get that it wouldn't matter upper or lower. I was having trouble finding the syntax to make the upper tri of one matrix the upper tri of another matrix, if that makes sense.